# How can I change or override a factor defined in JScience library?

Tags: java, units-of-measurement, jscience, jsr-275

JScience library implementation uses a set of values for converting units to each other. I am not sure they are defined as constants.

I would like to use my own conversion factor to convert meters to feet. Is there any way to accomplish that in JScience API?

Thanks

Comment: I downloaded the source codes and changed the values. That's the way only helped me at the moment least.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [JSR-363](http://unitsofmeasurement.github.io/), it went Final about a month ago, while JSR-275 never did. Extension modules like [UoM-Systems](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/uom-systems) help you to convert meters to feet, inch or other US Customary units. Let us know, either here or even better in the GitHub issue tracker(s) if there's something you're missing or you think does not work as intended.